# View JSON in Chrome Network response

Tags: json, ajax, google-chrome

I think I lost a feature or a configuration.
When you open inspector and inspect network requests, I used to see a formatted JSON tree when a Network request is returning a JSON string.

Now I had to add the console custom formatter and copy paste the JSON response in the console... pretty time consumer.

Do you think Chrome lost a feature or am I just dreaming ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try: network --> show overview --> select request on the left tab --> All --> Preview ?

Comment: @gaetanoM Yes exactly, I added a screenshot

Comment: This regression was fixed in Chrome 62: https://crbug.com/767393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw several older chrome' versions with the Json format feature, but as you said, on the newest... some versions of jsons (it might be related with the content type or format) is shown as a plain text. 
We've been using dbug.io since they beta released and it helps us deal with several jsons files.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I also suspect it's because of missing `Content-Type: application/json` header in the response

Comment: thank @Yabito Dany, I'm not dreaming. But though I will not use dbug, seems heavy to use for simple developpement debugging, chrome inspector is just awesome... exept this regressive feature.

Comment: @PetrPeller I'll try to add this header, I'll tell you if it's back

Comment: @PetrPeller Well played ! adding the header brings back the feature !!! Chrome is a bit more strict than before !